# Completely destroy Leaflet Map

Tags: android, leaflet, openstreetmap, leaflet.markercluster

I use [Leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com) along with the excellent [Leaflet Marker Clusterer](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) plugin to show a map in a Cordova Android app.  When the map is no longer in view I destroy it using

```
map.off();
map.remove();
```

based on suggestions I have found in other threads on this forum.  However, it is not clear to me that this is doing the job - for instance, I find that the marker clusterer layer persists.  Would destroying and recreating the map container DOM element at each subsequent map redraw be a method to ensure that everything on the map is destroyed with no memory leaks?

Comment: What do you mean by "the marker clusterer layer persists"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/5265 , either simply destroying the DOM elements, or removing their references does not free up memory: both need to be done in a consistent manner across all the code in order for things to work. Couple that with circular references between the map and the layers and you'll get leaks along the way.

AFAIK, the core Leaflet code will only leak one (and just one) reference to `L.Draggable` each time a map is destroyed. It's very possible that the MarkerCluster code does not clean up as good and internal circular references still persist.

Please also note that the changes done in https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/5265 are **not** part of the Leaflet 1.0.3 release.

So it's not a problem on how to use Leaflet (and Leaflet.MarkerCluster), it's a problem of how leaks happen in the internal code. (And contributions to fix that will be welcome)